# Defining a new LaTeX environment for numbered two-column proofs

Tags: environments

I'm trying to write up problem sets for my programming languages class, and I want to create an environment for a certain style of proof.  Proofs in this style will have two columns, with numbering on the left (starting at 1), like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{rc|l}  
(1) & Prop A & Justification \\  
(2) & Prop B & Justification \\  
(3) & Prop C & From (1) and (2)
\end{tabular}
```

I would like the numbering to happen automatically, without my having to add a column (like eqnarray does, with numbering on the right), and in perfect world, I would like to be able to use references and labels to refer to conclusions, so that if I insert steps or move them around I won't have to renumber everything.  Usage would hopefully look something like this:

```
\begin{twoproof}
Prop A & Justification \label{A} \\
Prop B & Justification \label{B} \\
Prop C & From \ref{A} and \ref{B}
\end{twoproof}
```

My very simplistic first attempt was this:

```
\newcounter{proofc}
\newenvironment{twoproof}{  
  \tabular{@{\stepcounter{proof} \arabic{proofc}}c|l}  
}{  
  \endtabular  
}
```

But not only will this not let me use `\ref` (I think), but whenever I try to use this environment I get this error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.  
<to be read again>   
               \csname\endcsname  
l.79 \begin{twoproof}
```

I tried running `\show\eqnarray` to see if I could use that as a template, but didn't understand the output at all, and I'm not sure where to look for enlightenment.

I will appreciate any help or direction that anyone might be able to provide!

---

**Edit2:**: I figured this issue out.  I tried to get clever and wrap my `twoproof` environments in `\begin{displaymath}` and `\end{displaymath}`, and I guess this environment doesn't play well with amstex, because when I changed the way I was defining `twoproof` and got rid of the `displaymath`, everything started working again.

**Edit**: While Willie Wong's answer (thankfully) solved my problem with with the missing `endcsname`, when I try to run this example:

```
\begin{twoproof}
\label{step1} Prop A & Justification \\
\label{step2} Prop B & Justification \\
Prop C & Because \ref{step1} and \ref{step2}
\end{twoproof}
```

I run into this error:

```
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'step1' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.56 \label
           {step2} Prop B & Justification \\
```

If anyone has any ideas about what might be causing this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, as long as I'm editing the question, does anyone know how to right-justify the numbering in the table?  It's not a big deal, but I think it might look a little nicer.  I've thought very briefly about setting up a custom `\halign`, but I don't think it's worth the effort.  If there's a (comparatively) easy solution, though, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm poking at your problem (unsuccessfully, so far), but allow me to offer a tip in the meantime: in general, use `\refstepcounter{foo}` to step the counter to which `\label{bar}`s refer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something `fragile` [strikes again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)! Try the following:

```
\newcounter{proofc}
\renewcommand\theproofc{(\arabic{proofc})}
\DeclareRobustCommand\stepproofc{\refstepcounter{proofc}\theproofc}
\newenvironment{twoproof}{\tabular{@{\stepproofc}c|l}}{\endtabular}
```

There's a small bug in this though: you have to put `\label` as the first thing in your row to work. It won't work if you put in the end. So

```
\begin{twoproof}
\label{step1} Prop A & Justification \\   \label{step2} Prop B & Justification \\   Prop C & Because \ref{step1} and \ref{step2}
\end{twoproof}
```

Comment: Why does the label have to come at the beginning?  What's `tabular` doing that hides the `\refstepcounter`?

Comment: Ahh this is perfect!  Thank you for your help.  This is also the first I've heard of fragile commands, so I'll have to see what I can find out about those.

Comment: @Antal: I don't know. My best guess is that it has something to do with the fact that each delimited entry in a tabular environment is put in a group. I hope someone more familiar with the TeX book can clarify.

Answer (score 4):

There are some existing packages that may fit your needs, such as [one of these packages for Fitch-style deductions](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) or [this one for Kalish-Montague style](http://www.rforge.com/). I use those regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also adapt [`listliketab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listliketab).